# Android Applications keep crashing

Tags: android, crash

I am a beginner, and I'm using treehouse to learn android development. On the two applications I have made, both have crashed starting today. I am unsure why this is happening because I have been following all of their instructions.

Main:

```
package com.example.personalityidentifier;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Personality mPersonality = new Personality();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String answer = mPersonality.getAPersonality();

            // Update label with dynamic answer
            answerLabel.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.personalityidentifier"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.personalityidentifier.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
07-10 10:47:22.870: D/AndroidRuntime(886): Shutting down VM
07-10 10:47:22.870: W/dalvikvm(886): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a78ba8)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886): Process: com.example.personalityidentifier, PID: 886
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.personalityidentifier/com.example.personalityidentifier.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at com.example.personalityidentifier.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-10 10:47:22.940: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  ... 11 more
07-10 10:47:26.170: I/Process(886): Sending signal. PID: 886 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace and what is `Personality`?

Answer (score 0):

Shot at the dark, remove Final in your TextView. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Error log will be better to know the issue,

Try out this.

**Step 1** : Create a BlankActivity.

[image]

**Step 2** :MainActivity.class

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setText("Hello Android!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Step 3 : Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hrh.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Click me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 4 :****Manifest File , Note* The theme must be of AppCompat look the style code below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hrh"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Step 5:**Style.xml in values dir.

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go   here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```